# Teams Bot typing animation disappearing before replies comes out

Tags: python, botframework

I have create teams bot using ms bot framework but sometimes typing animation disappears before the reply. what's causing this behavior. Following code shows the animation part.Am I doing something wrong here?

```
 async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
    # Get the state properties from the turn context.
    user_profile = await self.user_profile_accessor.get(turn_context, UserProfile)
    conversation_data = await self.conversation_data_accessor.get(turn_context, ConversationData)

    if user_profile.user_id is None:
        # First time around this is undefined, so we will store the user's ID.
        user_profile.user_id = turn_context.activity.from_property.id

    conversation_data.timestamp = self.__datetime_from_utc_to_local(
        turn_context.activity.timestamp
    )
    conversation_data.channel_id = turn_context.activity.channel_id

    response = None

    while response is None:
        typing_activity = Activity(type=ActivityTypes.typing)
        await turn_context.send_activity(typing_activity)

        response = chat(turn_context.activity.text, user_profile.user_id)

        # Introduce a delay before checking for response again.
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Sleep for 1 second before checking again.

    await turn_context.send_activity(f"{response}")
```